# How can I make Apple Shortcuts speak text in a different language than the one set for the device?

Tags: ios, macos, shortcut, ipados

My iPad Pro is set to work in language *x* (let’s say, English).

I’m writing a Shortcut that’s supposed to speak text in language *y* (let’s say, Italian).

Shortcuts instead speaks the text in English. How can I get to make it speak the text in Italian?

If the device is set to work in Italian, of course, everything works.

Thanks in advance for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Use Speak action : you can choose any language you want :
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Very kind of you.